# Call to a member function delete() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to delete a row from table. The function I used in controller is:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

However it throws me an error:

> Call to a member function delete() on null

when I check $post if it's empty with the code:

$post = Post::find($id);
dd($id);

I get the output:
"id => $post->id"

If i change
$post = Post::find(1);
It actually updates the deleted_at field in the database.

All the answers I've gotten so far only prevents the code from throwing an error.

Route Method:

```
Route::get('/post/delete/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'PostsController@destroy',
    'as' => 'post.delete'
]);
```

Code from the Blade file:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>

        <th>
            Title
        </th>

        <th>
            Edit
        </th>

        <th>
            Delete
        </th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>

    <td><img src="{{ $post->featured }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}" width="90px;" height="50px;"></td>
    <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td><a href="{{ route('post.delete',['id => $post->id']) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Trash</a></td>

    </tr>

    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check if `$post` is empty or not. it seems no post were found using the `$id` parameter. you can use `findOrFail` too.

Comment: when I check $post if it's empty with the code: 

$post = Post::find($id);
dd($id);

I get the output:
"id => $post->id"

If i change
$post = Post::find(1);
It actually updates the deleted_at field in the database.

All the answers I've gotten so far only prevents the code from throwing an error.

Comment: share your delete method. how are you trying to delete?? it seems your blade file is not parsing variable

Comment: public function destroy($id)
    {
    $post = Post::find($id);
    // dd($id);
    $post->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.');
    return redirect()->back();
}

That's the entire soft delete function I used in Laravel. Btw I'm pretty new to Laravel. @zahidhasanemon

Comment: i mean add your blade file from where you are trying to delete. and your route too.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon see snippets above.

Comment: check out my answer.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon it worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the problem is actually in your blade file, passing the parameter to the route. you are passing a parameter like `route('post.delete',['id => $post->id'])` which makes `id => $post->id` a single parameter as it is a string. you have to make it like

```
<a href="{{ route('post.delete',['id' => $post->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Trash</a>
```

as you are sending a single parameter you can write it just like

```
<a href="{{ route('post.delete',$post->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Trash</a>
```

now a bit of advice for you. never use a `get` request for deleting something. use either `post` request or `delete` request for deleting.

an example using `delete` request.

```
Route::delete('post/delete/{id}', 'PostsController@destroy')->name('post.delete');
```

now send a delete request from blade file using a form.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('post.delete', $post->id) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')    

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Trash</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been at this for weeks.

Answer (score 2):

> Call to a member function delete() on null

This error message means that you are trying to call method of the object which is  **not exist. null object.**

in this case, `Post::find($id)` returns **null**. because it couldn't find any record which is `$id`.

so your `$post` varaiable is null.

to dismiss the error messages, check `$post` variable is null.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if(empty($post)) {
        return;
    }

    $post->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better, take advantage of the [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding).

```
Route::delete('posts/{post}', 'PostsController@destroy')->name('post.delete');
```

In the controller:

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
    $post->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This will use `findOrFail` behind the scenes, so it will throw 404 if the post does not exist.

To use it in your view:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('post.delete', $post) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')    

    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::findorfail($id);
    $post->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle that as other answer and Here is another way! Which I prefer to use.

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $validator = Validator::make(compact('id'), [
        'id' => 'required|int|exists:posts,id'
    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response([ERROR_MESSAGE], [ERROR_CODE]);
    }

    $post = Post::find($id)->delete();
    return response([SUCCESS_MESSAGE], [SUCCESS_CODE]);
}
```

& To be more careful it's always better to put your code in "Try catch".

Answer (score 0):

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if(is_null($post)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $post->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.'); 

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use `findOrFail` helper function in laravel. You can handle exception is Post does not exist and show specific error message in front as below,

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    // Will return a ModelNotFoundException if no user with that id
    try
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'The post was just trashed.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    // catch(Exception $e) catch any exception
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'The post does not exist.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

This way your app will never crash. Hope this helps!